# .NET RESTFul API - What's the best way to store user session in memory?

Tags: .net, rest, c#-4.0

I'm java developer and totally new to .NET platform. Now i have a task to implement a method that create something like a session/token for the user.

It's a simple method, post without body, returns a token and store it in some place. This will be the first method that user will call.

Where is the best place to store key/value in .net? And what's the best way to create a random token?

Thanks in advance.

David L.

Comment: "Where is the best place to store key/value in .net?" -> A database. `And what's the best way to create a random token?` `Guid tok = new Guid()`.

Comment: I don't want to use a database for store a token that will expires after 1 hour. If it was a web app, i could store it in session but it's a webservice.

Comment: One hour is a long time. You can store the token expiration time, and run a job on a timer to purge the unwanted records. Unless you store it in the database, the thing would not survive bouncing of your web service.

Comment: By the way, i'm using a Singleton with ConcurrentDictionary and storing it HttpContext.Current.Application["object"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Web.Caching.Cache to get same results.
If you are on a web environment you should store cache items in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache